# Vorangestellter Genitiv — wie damit umgehen (wenn er noch überhaupt existiert)

Tags: preposition, genitive

Im Gegensatz zu

> das Haus des Schäfers

ist

> des Schäfers Haus

eine *Variante* (vertauschte Reihenfolge) des Genitivs, und zwar ein *vorangestellter Genitiv*. Die Frage Nummer null ist, ob dieser erste Versuch richtig ist. Jetzt die echten Fragen:

1. Klingt diese Reihenfolge befremdlich? Für mündliche Sprache offensichtlich schon, aber was ist mit schriftlich? Ist diese Reihenfolge in Zeitungen und Romanen — und nicht nur in Gedichten — üblich?
2. Davon unabhängig würde ich gerne die Struktur (genauer) verstehen. Wie man aus dem Titel erraten kann, hat die zweite (und Haupt-)Frage mit der Einfügung anderer Kasus zu tun.

Zum Beispiel wird

> *der Lernende des Begriffes*

durch Hinzufügen der Präposition *mit* zu

> *mit dem Lernenden des Begriffes*.

Wandeln wir diese Sätze in einen vorangestellten Genitiv um. Wird dann der Satz

> der Lernende des Begriffes

zu

- (a) *mit des Begriffes des Lernenden* oder
- (b) *mit des Begriffes der Lernende* (unglaubwürdig)?

Und was, wenn dieser vorangestellte Genitiv in einer Apposition auftritt? Z.B.

> Die Königin sagte dem König, dem genialen Schöpfer dieser originellen Theorie, „komm schon ins Bett“.

Wie muss dieser Satz dann umgewandelt werden?

- (a) Die Königin sagte dem König, dem dieser originellen Theorie genialen Schöpfer, „komm schon ins Bett“.
- (b) Die Königin sagte dem König, dem genialen dieser originellen Theorie Schöpfer, „komm schon ins Bett“.
- (c) Die Königin sagte dem König, dieser originellen Theorie dem genialen Schöpfer, „komm schon ins Bett“
- (d) Andere Variante.

Comment: Zwei nicht mit der Frage zusammenhängende Anmerkungen zu den Beispielen: 1) *Student + Genitiv* wird eigentlich nur bei Fachgebieten u. Ä. verwandt (z. B. *Student der Physik, Student des Gitarrenspiels*), nicht bei elementaren Lerninhalten wie Begriffen. Deshalb würde ich vermutlich eher eine Konstruktion wie »derjenige, der den Begriff lernt* wählen. 2) Sehr wahrscheinlich ist im zweiten Beispiel *originell* und nicht *original* gemeint.

Comment: Wenn schon, dann „dem Schäfer sein Haus“, sonst wäre die Besitzanzeige doppelt.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft schlägst du etwa eine Veränderung des Nomens ,,Begriff" vor? kann ich machen, aber welches Nomen kann ich nutzen, damit ein bestimmter Artikel noch Sinn macht?

Comment: @c.p.: Nein, eher eine Änderung des Nomens *Student* (z. B. zu *Lernender*). Für genauere Empfehlungen müsste ich besser wissen, worum es geht.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft schon gemacht. Jetzt weiß ich aber nicht, wie man *Lernender* beugt...

Comment: Das erste Beispiel muss heißen "des Schäfers Haus"; weder "sein Haus" noch "das Haus".

Comment: Zu Frage 1: (Reihenfolge statt Ordnung wäre meist besser - ich würde gerne korrigieren, aber wüsste nicht wo ich aufhören soll): Welche Reihenfolge soll komisch sein - die erste oder die zweite?

Comment: Danke @userunknown Das mit der Ordnung hat mich total irritiert. Ich wusste gar nichts damit anzufangen. :D

Comment: Leider ist "Lernender" ein sehr weiter Begriff - man kann so vieles lernen, etwa Begriffe. Lernender ist aber selbst ein Begriff, und das schafft viele Interpretationsspielräume. Mir ist nicht klar, ob ich die Frage richtig verstanden habe. Geht es um den Begriff, der die Person die lernt bezeichnet: `Der Begriff des Lernenden` im Sinne von `Der Begriff des Schlafenden`? Oder geht es um das, was der Lernnende benutzt, um dessen Begriffe? Wie etwa um seine Formeln, Bücher, Stifte und Zirkel? `Der Zirkel des Lernenden`? Ich hoffe meine Korrekturen waren richtig.

Comment: Mir ist gerade ein solcher Genitiv in einem ganz normalen Text begegnet, ohne dass er meiner Meinung nach altertümlich klänge: [Anderer Länder Militärequipment nachzubauen ist ja immer nicht so einfach.](http://blog.fefe.de/?ts=ac99ac68)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich bezeichne im Folgenden das Wort, dem der Genitiv zugeordnet wird, als *Substantiv.* Außerdem schreibe ich nicht über die normalen vorangestellten Genitive von Eigennamen. Der Reihe nach:

0) Der vorangestellte Genitiv ersetzt einen bestimmten Artikel, es ist also »des Schäfers Haus« (das Haus des Schäfers) oder »eines Schäfers Haus« (das Haus eines Schäfers). Soll das Substantiv unbestimmt sein (wenn als der Schäfer im Beispiel mehrere Häuser hat), funktioniert das meines Wissens nur mit dem nachgestellten Genitiv: »Ein Haus des Schäfers.«

1) Ein vorangestellter Genitiv klingt wohl immer altertümlich, wird aber manchmal eingesetzt um gerade diese Wirkung zu erhalten. Relativ häufig ist der Einsatz in Überschriften u. Ä., um diese wie den Titel eines Märchens wirken zu lassen, z. B.: *Des Ministers alte Probleme* (vergleiche mit [des Kaisers neue Kleider](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Des_Kaisers_neue_Kleider)). Verwandt hiermit gibt es auch einige feste oder teilweise feste Ausdrücke, in denen der vorangestellte Genitiv verwendet wird, z. B. »der Tragödie dritter Teil« (wobei *Tragödie* und *dritter* jeweils durch ähnliche Begriffe ersetzt werden können, z. B. »des Filmes dritter Akt«). Je komplizierter das Konstrukt mit vorangestelltem Genitiv, desto stärker die archaische Wirkung und desto höher die Chance, dass Muttersprachler es nicht verstehen.

2) Das Substantiv wird dekliniert. Es ist also »mit des Begriffes Studenten«. Adjektive des Substantivs werden stark dekliniert (wie beim vorangestellten Genitiv von Eigennamen), z. B.: »des Kaisers neue**r** Gebrauchtwagen«. Im zweiten Beispiel würde ich daher Folgendes wählen:

> Die Königin sagte dem König, dieser originalen Theorie genialem Schöpfer: „komm schon ins Bett“.

Aber auch nur, wenn es unbedingt ein vorangestellter Genitiv sein muss, denn die Konstruktion mutet schon sehr seltsam an und ist schwer zu verstehen.

Comment: Braucht man, also, keinen Artikel für "Schöpfer" in die Aposition? D.h. ist es möglich, eine Aposition ohne Artikel?

Comment: Nein, der vorgestellte Genitiv ersetzt gewissermaßen einen bestimmten Artikel – wie das auch bei dem vorgestellten Genitiv von Eigennamen der Fall ist: »Ich sah Bello, Erwins Hund, durch den Garten rennen.«

Comment: ich würde schreiben *"dieser originellen Theorie genialem Schöpfer"*, weiß aber selber nicht genau warum. weißt du vielleicht wieso? außerdem glaube ich *der dritter Tragödie Teil* ist nicht korrekt ;) bitte versuch doch klarer darzustellen, wie die Austauschbarkeit funktioniert. (dritter Teil der Tragödie / der dritte Teil der Tragödie)

Comment: @Vogel612, er meint wohl, dass ebenso „des Schauspiels zweiter Akt“ funktioniert. Das Dativ-m hielte ich aber auch für erforderlich.

Comment: @Vogel612/Carsten Schultz: Ich habe *der Tragödie dritter Teil* genauer erläutert. Und ja, es muss ein Dativ-m sein (keine Ahnung, was mich da geritten hat), was jetzt auch erläutert wird.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft ich wette das kommt von (wem sagte die Königin?) *"dem genialen Schöpfer"* als Akkusativ

Comment: @Vogel612: Welcher Akkusativ?

Comment: Man muss sich nur vorstellen, die originelle Theorie hieße Erwin, dann erhält man „Erwins genialem Schöpfer“ :)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft BRAINFART..... ich scahu das grad an und denk mir nur... was für einen Unsinn hab ich denn da verzapft