# Collecting data on prepositions, looking for counter-examples

Tags: preposition, phrase, grammatical-case, phrase-request

I’m collecting data on phrases with two-way prepositions. These are the prepositions that can go with either Dativ or Akkusativ case depending on the usage (an, auf, hinter, in, neben, über, unter, vor, zwischen, and entlang¹).

An initial is to create a list of 2-grams consisting of preposition and article, e.g., *über die,* which can be either feminine or plural Akkusativ. The list:

- *über die* (Akkusative feminine or Akkusative plural)
- *über das* (Akkusative neutral)
- *über der* (Dativ feminine)
- *über dem* (Dativ masculine or Dativ neutral)
- *über den* (Akkusativ masculine or Dativ plural)

My question: Are there any phrases that contain a member of this list that doesn’t fall in the specified category? Using the Google N-gram viewer, I can only find the 10 most common occurences (see [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%BCber%20der%20*&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t2;,%C3%BCber%20der%20*;,c0;,s0;;%C3%BCber%20der%20Erde;,c0;;%C3%BCber%20der%20Zeit;,c0;;%C3%BCber%20der%20Stadt;,c0;;%C3%BCber%20der%20Mitte;,c0;;%C3%BCber%20der%20ganzen;,c0;;%C3%BCber%20der%20Spree;,c0;;%C3%BCber%20der%20rechten;,c0;;%C3%BCber%20der%20Schulter;,c0;;%C3%BCber%20der%20Natur;,c0;;%C3%BCber%20der%20Brust;,c0) for an example). **Is there ever literary or poetic wording where the word order is atypical and, for example, *über der* can ever be used such that *der* is the Nominativ masculine?** Punctuation between words matters, so *über, der* is distinct from *über der.*

---

¹ [entlang](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entlang) is a postposition when used in the Akkusativ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list is complete. Just to be strict, there's something you might want to consider:

In a poetic context you might stumble upon a [*vorangestellter Genitiv*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8359/vorangestellter-genitiv-wie-damit-umgehen-wenn-er-noch-uberhaupt-existiert):

> …, der **über der** Königin lange Haaren spricht. (notice the absence of the coma)

which actually means:

> …, der **über** die langen Haaren **der** Königin spricht.

By the same token,

> …, der **über des** Königs Thron spricht.

As you say, it would be common to find *über, der*. For instance:

> Wir setzen den Fluss über, der …

There *der* is nominative, but there is a coma.

Comment: Super. this is exactly the exception I was looking for.

Comment: the presentation of the example clauses is incomplete. to complicate matters, there are 2 readings engendering different case marking. 1. `über der königin langen haaren` (über [location] den langen haaren der königin) *(above the queen's long hair)*; 2. `über der königin lange haare` (über [theme] die langen haare der königin) *(about the queen's long hair)*.

Comment: @collapsar which is beyond the scope of the question. I think the OP understands which is the appropriate case. But I do agree that adding a verb would be better. So, I did that.

Comment: @c.p. your corrections require a minor morphological adjustment in the case marking of `lange Haare` (`n` suffix dropped).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to c.p.'s answer, there is also the case of attributes prepending a noun in plural. Cases relevant for this question can occur

- for any transitive, non-reflexive verb.
- for adjective with direct objects (Is this the correct term?).

**Transitive, non-reflexive verbs**

> Ich rede über der Hilfe bedürfende Kinder. (der=genitive feminine)
>
> Über der Toten gedenkende Menschen hinweg sah man die Grabsteine. (der=genitive plural)

**Adjective with direct objects**

> Über den der Akten kundigen Richter sah der Angeklagte schon die Gefängnisfenster. (der=genitive feminine)

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful (and renders my project kaput).