# Is "Augen hat des Menschen Bild" a matter of style or grammar?

Tags: grammaticality, genitive, style

> **Augen hat des Menschen Bild**,
>
> hingegen Licht der Mond.

I am particularly troubled by the first line quoted here from Friedrich Hölderlin's *In lieblicher Bläue*.

**Augen hat des Menschen Bild** seems to make no grammatical sense: `Augen = eyes`; `hat = has`; `des Menschen = the people's` (genitive case); `Bild = picture`.

How do you put all this together intelligibly? **Eyes has picture of the people?** That would be the closest version to a sentence actually making sense. If so, why **hat** and not **haben**, to agree with **Augen**? Why not **die Augen haben das Bild des Menschen** (instead of the more natural, in my opinion, **die Augen sind das Bild des Menschen**)? Is this what the poet actually meant: **die Augen sind das Bild des Menschen**? And why are both **Augen** and **Bild** without their respective definite articles?

Comment: The subject is “des Menschen Bild”. “Der Mensch” means “the man” (in the sense of human), but in English one would, I think, not use an article here.

Comment: @CarstenS I know what _der Mensch_ means. But there is no "_der_ Mensch" in this text; it is "_des_ Menschen." And if the subject is _des Menschen Bild_, how do you translate that into English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

„Des Menschen Bild“ is an archaic/poetical genitive construction, moving the genitive noun in front of the subject noun (in German: „vorangestellter Genitiv“). In modern German, one would say "das Bild des Menschen":

> „Das Bild des Menschen hat Augen, der Mond hat Licht.“
>
> "The people's / man's sight / picture has eyes, the moon has light"

For „Bild“, i would propose "sight" instead of "picture", because the preceding lines tell of someone looking into a mirror. That's also the reason for proposing "man" instead of "people" - it's a person spotting his own mirror image:

> Wenn einer in den Spiegel siehet,
> ein Mann, und siehet darinn sein Bild, wie abgemahlt;
> es gleicht dem Manne.
> Augen hat des Menschen Bild,
> hingegen Licht der Mond.

([Bibliotheca Augustana](https://www.hs-augsburg.de/%7Eharsch/augustana.html): [In lieblicher Bläue](https://www.hs-augsburg.de/%7Eharsch/germanica/Chronologie/19Jh/Hoelderlin/hoe_0801.html))

Regarding the missing definite article: i can't provide a source, but i would generally expect the subject noun to be definite in such a construction. At least, i didn't find an example where the subject is indefinite.

Comment: Where could I find all these peculiarities of archaic German explained? Could you please recommend me a book that has them all explained? Like a historical grammar, maybe... (And about this archaic genitive construction: my intuition was correct that this could only mean _das Bild des Menschen_, right?)

Comment: I'm very sorry, but i would have to search for such books first. There are some examples for that construction at [Wikipedia on Genitive (german)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitiv#Attributiver_Genitiv).

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328, maybe this is helpful: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8359/vorangestellter-genitiv-wie-damit-umgehen-wenn-er-noch-überhaupt-existiert

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328, yes *das Bild des Menschen* and *des Menschen Bild* mean the same thing.  Both are correct, you can use them. The first is the "normal" one. Similarly, *das Bild Alfreds* and *Alfreds Bild* mean the same and can both be used. Here, the second one is the "normal" choice.

Comment: I'd suggest sticking with *image* instead of *sight*, as the man's eyes may have 'light' in the poetic sense of "seine Augen leuchteten", which is not the case for the image in the mirror.  *Sight* here to me makes no sense.

Comment: The best translation for „Bild“ would deserve a question on its own, but anyway, it would fit better on https://english.stackexchange.com. Maybe i should remove my remarks regarding the english translation?

Comment: Is there a reason why there is no "s" added on to "Bild" to let you know that is the Genitive noun?

Comment: @BlauKakapoW: The genitive noun is "des Menschen". "Bild" has nominative case.