# Warum gibt es diese Wortfolge des Genitivs: "Der Hölle Rache kocht in meinem Herzen"

Tags: word-order

Wenn ich die Bedeutung nicht verstanden habe, sollte es nicht sein

> "Die Rache der Hölle..."?

Comment: Geht beides. Siehe auch: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8359/vorangestellter-genitiv-wie-damit-umgehen-wenn-er-noch-überhaupt-existiert

Comment: @Carsten Ich markierte als Duplikat

Comment: Gut. Ich war mir nicht sicher, ob die andere Frage verständlich genug ist.

Comment: @CarstenS Die dort akzeptierte Antwort ist richtig und ziemlich gut. Die Frage dazu ist allerdings ein bisschen verschwurbelt formuliert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vorangestellter Genitiv, klare Sache. Der Grund dürfte sein, das jambische Versmaß durchgängig zu halten. Man könnte noch fragen: Wohin ist der zweite Artikel verschwunden (*die* Rache *der* Hölle)? Da geht es um Definitheit. Grammatische Definitheit wie beim bestimmten Artikel lässt sich auch "possessiv" erzielen. Wenn ich frage 'welche Rache', kann die Antwort sein: 'diese Rache' ('demonstrativ' + 'deiktisch' bzw. 'zurück- oder vorausverweisend') oder 'ihre Rache' ("possessiv") bzw. auch 'die Rache der Hölle' ('attributiv'). Hier verweist der Artikel 'die' auf eine Bestimmtheit, die entweder bereits geliefert wurde (*die Rache, von der schon die Rede war*) oder die noch folgen wird (*die Rache, die ich sogleich näher bestimmen werde*), wobei die Bestimmung durch das Genitivattribut erfolgt. Wenn das Genitivattribut jedoch vorgezogen wird, ist die Bestimmtheit bereits vorgenommen worden und der Artikel 'die' damit hinfällig. Man könnte sagen, dass das vorgezogene Genitivattribut Artikelfunktion hat.