# "Meiner Mutter Vater" -"Der Vater meiner Mutter"

Tags: sentence-structure, standard-german, genitive

> Der Chef meines Vaters ist Koch

ist das genauso möglich wie

> Meines Vaters Chef ist Koch

gegen welche grammatikalischen Regeln wird hier verstoßen? (wenn überhaupt)

Comment: "Meinem Mutters Vater ist Koch" ist nicht korrekt. Es geht aber "Meiner Mutter Vater is Koch". Warum man allerdings von seinem Großvater so geschraubt sprechen sollte, erschließt sich mir  nicht. Wenn es denn sein soll, schlage ich "Mein Großvater mütterlicherseits ist Koch" vor. PS. Erinnert mich an die Redewendung "Der Schwiegervater meiner Mutter", die ich mal gehört habe.

Comment: @PaulFrost das Beispiel ist schlecht gewählt, mir ist das auch sofort aufgefallen.

"Meines Vaters Chef ist ein Arsch" - "Der Chef meines Vaters ist ein Arsch"
"Meiner Mutters Vater ist Koch" -"Der Vater meiner Mutter ist Koch" 

Das geht also?

Comment: Beides ist möglich und richtig. Es wird gegen überhaupt keine Regel verstoßen.

Comment: Der erste Teil der Überschrift ist nicht korrekt. *Meiner* ist ein Artikelwort, daher bekommt *Mutter* kein Genitiv-s, also: *meiner Mutter Vater*. Siehe etwa https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/3428

Comment: @PaulFrost: So eine Formulierung kann dazu verwendet werden, eine persönliche Distanz auszudrücken. Ich habe beispielsweise eine Bekannte, die kein gutes Verhältnis zu ihrem Bruder hat und ihn ausschließlich als "der Sohn meiner Eltern" bezeichnet.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das ist plausibel. Das von mir erwähnte "Der Schwiegervater meiner Mutter" hatte allerdings andere Gründe: Die Großeltern väterlicherseits waren tot, aber die Mutter sprach immer wieder mal von ihrer Schwiegermutter bzw. ihrem Schwiegervater, so dass sich das in dieser Form festsetzte.

Comment: Auch der Titel der Frage sollte geändert werden.

Comment: Siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8359/vorangestellter-genitiv-wie-damit-umgehen-wenn-er-noch-%c3%bcberhaupt-existiert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Genitivattribute können auf zwei verschiedene Arten gebildet werden. Bei der einen Art steht das Attribut vor dem Nomen auf das es sich bezieht, bei der anderen steht es dahinter.

- Genitivattribut vor Bezugswort (Linksattribut)

  > ***Meiner Schwester** Kleid* ist rot.
  > ***Des Bäckers** Wohnung* liegt im ersten Stock.
  > ***Georgs** Auto* steht in der Garage.
  > Jeder ist ***seines Glückes** Schmied.*
- Genitivattribut hinter Bezugswort (Rechtsattribut)

  > *Das Kleid **meiner Schwester*** ist rot.
  > *Die Wohnung **des Bäckers*** liegt im ersten Stock.
  > *Das Auto **des Georg*** steht in der Garage.
  > Jeder ist *der Schmied **seines Glückes.***

Beide Versionen sind korrekt, aber sie werden in unterschiedlichen Konstellationen unterschiedlich häufig verwendet:

- Attribut ist ein Personenname

  > (fast) immer: ***Georgs** Auto* steht in der Garage.
  > so gut wie nie: *Das Auto **des Georg*** steht in der Garage.

  Der Grund dafür ist, dass Personennamen meist ohne Artikel verwendet werden, das ist aber nur mit einem Linksattribut kompatibel. Rechtsattribute benötigen immer ein [Determinativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinativ_(Wortart)) (Artikel, Pronomen, ...)
- In bestimmten Redewendungen

  > (fast) immer: Jeder ist ***seines Glückes** Schmied.*
  > so gut wie nie: Jeder ist *der Schmied **seines Glückes.***

  Hier handelt es sich um feste Fügungen ("in Teufels Küche kommen" "etwas in Gottes Hand legen", "das Bessere ist des Guten Feind", ...) die schon vor langer Zeit entstanden sind und bei denen sich die Formulierung als Linksattribut bis heute gehalten hat.
- alte und gehobene Sprache
  In alten Texten (z.B. Liedtexten) und in Literatur, die in gehobener Sprache verfasst wurde, begegnet man häufiger als sonst dem Linksattribut

  > Ferne glänzt ***des Weihers** Spiegel*
  > Es schwankt ***der Schwester** Schatten*
- In allen anderen Fällen
  In allen anderen Fällen dominiert das Rechtsattribut

  > (fast) immer: *Das Kleid **meiner Schwester*** ist rot.
  > so gut wie nie: ***Meiner Schwester** Kleid* ist rot.

---

Zu beachten ist auch, dass die richtige Genitivendung verwendet werden muss (*»Georgs Auto«* aber *»das Auto des Georg«*). Das ist aber ein ganz eigenes und schwieriges Kapitel, das ich hier nicht behandeln möchte.

---

Ich möchte noch ergänzen, dass es auch mit einem Präpositionalattribut möglich ist, Besitz- bzw. Zugehörigkeitsverhältnisse anzuzeigen. In diesem Fall ist nur das Rechtsattribut möglich:

> *Das Kleid **von meiner Schwester*** ist rot.
> *Die Wohnung **vom Bäcker*** liegt im ersten Stock.
> *Das Auto **vom Georg*** steht in der Garage.

Diese Variante gilt aber als umgangssprachlich und sollte in Texten, in denen es auf stilsichere Ausdrucksweise ankommt, nicht verwendet werden.

---

In Gegenden, in denen bairische Dialekte vorherrschen (z.B. Bayern, Österreich) findet man auch diese Variante, die wiederum nur als Linksattribut gibt:

> ***Meiner Schwester** ihr Kleid* ist rot.
> ***Dem Bäcker** seine Wohnung* liegt im ersten Stock.
> ***Dem Georg** sein Auto* steht in der Garage.

Beachte, dass das Attribut im Dativ steht und sich zwischen Attribut und Kern noch ein Possessivpronomen befindet.

Aber Vorsicht! Diese Variante gilt im nördlichen Bereich Deutschlands als falsch und gehört definitiv nicht zum Standarddeutsch. Weil sie aber im Süden sehr häufig verwendet wird, sollte man diese Konstruktion zumindest gut genug kennen um sie zu verstehen. Wenn man Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernt, sollte man diese Konstruktion aber besser nicht aktiv verwenden.

Comment: _Das Auto Georgs_ geht auch noch, dass sollte vielleicht ergänzt werden.

Comment: "Dem Georg sein Auto" ist auch im Hessischen üblich.