# Es ward, dass sein der Menschen reinste pflegen

Tags: literature, poetry

There is this passage from the Gralserzählung from Lohengrin:

> Drin ein Gefäß von wundertät’gem Segen
> Wird dort als höchstes
> Heiligtum bewacht. 
> Es ward, dass sein der Menschen reinste pflegen,
> Herab von einer Engelschar gebracht.

How does one parse the third line grammatically? In english it's "It was to be cared for by the purest of man". What trips me up is the positioning of sein. Is it to be read as "der Menschen (dativ) sein reinste" = "Mankind's purest?", in which case 'sein' should have been 'ihr'. In addition, there seems to be no object for pflegen.

Answer (score 6):

The full text can be found [here](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Wagner,+Richard/Musikdramen/Lohengrin/3.+Akt/3.+Szene?hl=engelschar), and the interesting part is:

> es ward, daß sein der Menschen Reinste pflegen,
> herab von einer Engelschar gebracht;

Note, that *Reinste* is uppercase here indicating use as substantive.

This translates to:

> To be taken care of by the purest of mankind, it was brought down [i. e. from heaven] by a group of  angels.

*Sein* actually poetically refers to the *Gral* (more exact: the *Gefäß* from the previous clause) and it is exactly the object of  *pflegen* you did not find elsewhere.

*der Menschen Reinste* is also poetic/dated construct, the left-hand attribute,  which is addressed in [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/61654/1696) German answer.

Update to reflect comments:

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/pflegen#1) shows in the last example a dated use of *pflegen* with genitive from Schiller.

Comment: I would interpret *sein* as a shortened form of *seiner* which means it's a genitive object.

Comment: @RHa Interesting! Is it common in the past to have verbs to take the genitive object in cases where the akkusative would have been used today? In another passage (Einsam in trüben Tagen) Elsa says "des Ritters will ich wahren, er soll mein Streiter sein"

Comment: @ZhanfengLim Yes, that's a somewhat common pattern. Another example is "vergessen". Current usage "Vergiss mich nicht", old usage: "Vergiß meiner nicht", shortened: "Vergiß mein nicht", which is the name of a flower ("Vergißmeinnicht"). Quite parallel to what is happening in the Lohengrin verse.

Comment: In *Lohengrin*, Wagner used the genitive a lot, maybe in order to make the language sound archaic: *Nie sollst du mich befragen, noch **Wissens** Sorge tragen, woher ich kam **der Fahrt**, noch wie mein Nam’ und Art!*

Comment: @RHa Interesting to know that such uses of the Genitiv is considered archaic even in Wagner's time! I thought that it would have been more normal to write this way during his time. I know the passage you just mentioned, but never knew 'der Fahrt' was in genitiv (after all it could have been Dativ). How would one translate the sentence 'woher ich kam der Fahrt' here? I'm quite interested in archaic german.

Answer (score 3):

From DWDS for [sein](https://www.dwds.de/wb/sein#2)

It is using outdated language which is probably what's confusing. "Sein" in this case is a Personalpronomen like "Ihm","Ihn" or "Ihr"

So you could write it as

> "Es ward, dass ihn der Menschen Reinste pflegen ..."

Your translation is pretty spot on I feel:

> It was to be cared for by the purest of man
> Es ward, dass sein der Menschen reinste pflegen

"to be cared for" moves to the end of the sentence here as "pflegen"
"the purest of man" becomes "der Menschen Reinste"
While "sein" simply refers to "him" the Gral

Comment: "Sein' would stand for "es" then (das Gefäß), not "ihn", though. "Es ward, dass es der Menschen Reinste pflegen, ...".

Comment: @HalvarF We're not talking about "Das Gefäß" -> es
We're talking about  "Der Gral" -> ihn

Comment: At this point nothing about 'der Gral' is mentioned though, it only appears in the next paragraph, so grammatically does it not have to refer to das Gefäss?

Thanks for the informative answer! Something new I learnt today again about the German language!

Comment: @ZhanfengLim I think if the author had wanted it to remain more "mysterious" or not be specific until later he could have referred to it as an "es", but grammatically the author (or translator) would be aware of what he is referring to and should use the masculine form. It might also be helpful that things similar to a Gral would be "der Becher", "Der Kelch" which are "non-holy" versions of the Gral. Das Gefäss doesn't really fit that well in the context anyway in my opinion. Glad I could help!

Comment: @Trae:  Disagree. The sentence literally starts with "Es ward...", which refers to the same noun and thing, "das Gefäß". It makes no sense to change gender in the middle of a sentence for the same thing, in reference to a noun that wasn't even used at that point. "sein" is used because it is a genitive (neutrum) and maybe because it fits the metrum better to have a strong word at that place.

Comment: @HalvarF "Es ward" is referring to "something happening" and is not referring to any noun. The english equivalent would be saying "And so it was" the "it" here also doesn't refer to any specific thing

Comment: @Trae: No. Read the whole verse. You own translation "It was, to be cared for by the purest of man, ..." contradicts your statement. "Es ward, dass [....], herab von einer Engelschar gebracht.". "Es ward gebracht" - nämlich das Gefäß.

Comment: @HalvarF I'll have to admit to answering a bit lazily in the last comment, so let me try to add some actual info here. From https://www.dwds.de/wb/es#1 under 4.
"dient der Hervorhebung und Satzbelebung" Examples: "es meldeten sich immer neue Gäste an", "es sind nicht alle Schlangen giftig" Let's take these examples from dwds, in both cases the gender of the object would not be neutral, yet it is used in front. Hope I finally managed to explain it better!

Comment: I understood what you were saying, but it's not the case here. You need a subject later in the sentence if you're using "es" in the way you are talking about. "Neue Gäste" and "alle Schlangen" are the ones in the DWDS examples. "Es ward, dass sein der Menschen Reinste pflegen, herab von einer Engelschar gebracht." doesn't have such a later subject. "Es" (=das Gefäß) is the only subject here.

Comment: @HalvarF Fair point, it doesn't really fit with what I linked.  To me the start of it just seems the same as the usage in things like "Es war finster" which I wasn't able to find yesterday. Last attempt to justify myself: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/es_das_man under 3. c) bei Zustands- und Artsätzen
Grammatik
ist Subjekt in unpersönlichen Ausdrücken Examples es ist Nacht, es war schon spät.   If you find a reason why that also doesn't find I won't know why it is first "es" then "sein" anymore